# For command syntax error in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to execute a command for every folder with the name "day*".

The following is my code:

```
FOR /D [/r] %%G IN (\tool\%server%\%day*) DO (
    ***code to copy and paste from one folder to another***
)
```

My computer gives me the following errors:

```
[/r] was unexpected at this time
```

when I tried removing `[/r]`

```
%%G was unexpected at this time
```

Comment: remove the rectangular brackets.

Comment: Rectangular brackets in syntax means something optional.

Comment: I assume you are testing this not with a batch file but within the CMD itself. If so, you need to use `%G` instead of `%%G`. Also, your wildcard doesn't need a `%` in the front as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read API documentation for newbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs)

Comment: [What do the brackets around the arguments mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21654192/995714), [What do square brackets mean in function/class documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1718903/995714)

Comment: DOS doesn't have `for /r`. It's a feature of cmd.exe [which is a different environment](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Comment: Here is the [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771080(v=ws.11)) that explains the documentation syntax.