# what does this syntax means p.then(onFulfilled[, onRejected])

Tags: javascript

in the MDN documentation i have seen it many times
for example

```
p.then(onFulfilled[, onRejected]);
```

this method takes two functions callbacks that I understand but why
in the syntax example provided by MDN there is brackets like its an array and to add to my confusion there is a comma in the beginning or maybe this doesn't mean an array at all and means something else
i know it might be something really small or trivial but i cant find relative information regarding this
thank you so much for helping

Comment: That's a documentation syntax, brackets mean that the parameter is optional.

Comment: You see it in lots of other contexts, too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1718903/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/21654192/3001761

Comment: You can find more info in the MDN [document structure docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Structures/Syntax_sections#formal_syntax)